# Can you easily buy bus tickets in China during Chinese New Year?

Tags: public-transport, china, transportation, public-holidays, shanghai

I'm looking for ways to get out of Shanghai at the beginning of Chinese New Year holiday season (21-22 January, possibly one or two days earlier). Seeing that all train tickets, including those for G trains, are already gone, I wonder if one can still find a bus ticket. I will be in Shanghai starting from 15 January; do you think there are any chances? Failing that, is it feasible to hitchhike in Chunyun season?

I'm flexible about destination: Wuhan, Changsha, Nanchang or anywhere else where I can continue to Guangzhou.

Comment: Good luck, CNY is a very busy travel time and even if you do get out of Shanghai, chances are Guangzhou will be just as difficult to travel to.

Comment: @Tom Surprisingly enough, tickets to Guangzhou are still available. I plan to stay thereabouts for a weak, then exit China on 28-29 February, which is the eye of the storm when it comes to transportation options.

Comment: If you are going to look, I would snag a ticket if you find one open. Chinese New Year is perhaps the one time of year where nearly everyone, and I mean everyone, is traveling from the city to the rural areas to celebrate with relatives (mainly grandparents). So it is possible, you'll have to look very hard. Basically, buy a ticket as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you delay your departure by 1-2 days or just take a flight? Train tickets are personalized (passport number and is checked) so I wouldn't get an illicit one unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: I think Chinese New Year is in late January this year, not late February

Comment: @k-t-l-lo this is funny and yes you are right. I meant January, not February. Edited.